# Visual Studio 2010 not connecting to Oracle

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, oracle11g, odac

Here is my environment:

64-bit Operating System, x64 based processor
Windows 10 Enterprise
Visual Studio 2010
Oracle Client 64 11gR2
ODAC 64k
ODAC 32k

The issue is I can't get Visual Studio 2010 connecting to Oracle 11g Database.

Tried Oracle.DataAccess.DLL from Oracle Client 64 11gR2, ODAC 64k and ODAC32k, no success.

Also tried to set .NET framework to 4 and 2, no luck.

Also tried System.Data.OracleClient, it complains abount 32bit and 64bit conflict

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=CustomerDB;User ID=userid;Password=password"
    Dim conn As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(oradb)
    Response.Write(conn.Database.ToString())
    Response.Write(conn.State.ToString)
    conn.Open()
    Dim sql As String = "select name from customer where CustID=1"
    Dim cmd As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand(sql, conn)
    Dim dr As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    dr.Read()
    Response.Write(dr.Item("name"))
    conn.Close()
    conn.Dispose()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio itself is not 64-bit. You will need to install the 32-bit components to be able to connect Visual Studio to Oracle.

Comment: ODAC 32 has been installed yet, accordingly reference has been added in the project yet no luck.

Comment: @kkazi Oh so it's *your* program that cannot connect. Well we cannot say, you will need to post actual code and an error message.

Comment: Thanks @nvoigt for looking into the issue.

<br>
Okay, I have now installed Oracle Client 32 bit as well and copied the Oracle.DataAccess.dll into the Bin folder, from where I have added the file as reference in the project.
<br>
And still receiving this error in the 3rd line of the code _conn.Open()_
<br>

Comment: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Oracle.DataAccess
  StackTrace:
       at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
       at _Default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\inetpub\OracleTest1\Default.aspx.vb:line 8

Comment: Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=CustomerDB;User ID=userid;Password=password"
        Dim conn As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(oradb)
        conn.Open()

Comment: Please don't post your code as comments. Please use the edit option in your question to put in your code there.